# Question about the definition of the associative algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra), an associative algebra is defined as follows:

> Let $R$ be a fixed commutative ring. An associative $R$-algebra is an
>   additive abelian group $A$ which has the structure of both a ring and an
>   $R$-module in such a way that ring multiplication is $R$-bilinear:
>
> $r\cdot(xy) = (r\cdot x)y = x(r\cdot y)$ for all $r \in R$ and $x, y \in A$.

My question is that how about requiring just $r(xy)=(rx)y$? I have no clear idea why it also requires $x(ry)$ to be equal. It seems unnatural to me. Is there any motivation about the requirement? Or is there any pathologic or weird examples if it just requires $r(xy)=(rx)y$?

Answer (score 1):

We have to translate the sentence "ring multiplication is $R$-bilinear". Let $m:A\times A\to A$ denote this map. Then "$m$ is $R$-bilinear" means that the maps $$m^x:A\to A\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,y\mapsto xy$$ and $$m_y:A\to A \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\mapsto xy$$ are both $R$-linear for every $x,y\in A$.

Translation: for every $r\in R$, we have $m^x(r.y)=r.m^x(y)$ and $m_y(r.x)=r.m_y(x)$. In other words, we have $x(r.y)=r.(xy)$ and $(r.x)y=r.(xy)$. Summarizing:

$$r.(xy)=x(r.y)=(r.x)y.$$

(Note the different notation for $m^x$ and $m_y$: in $m^x$ we have fixed the *first* variable to be constantly $=x$, and in $m_y$ the *second* variable is always equal to $y$.)